# configure.ac "post script"

Tags: configure, autotools

I'm encountering the need to run a script after configure is done, automatically.
That is, when I run ./configure  I would like it to end up by running ./script.sh, and it must be the last thing the configure runs.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if [AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Configuration-Commands) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Almost... This macro "Execute the cmds right after creating config.status.". I need something that will run right after <b>config.status is run<b>...

Comment: And  [AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Configuration-Commands) isn't what you're after either?

Answer (score 0):

You can put any arbitrary shell code in your configure.ac. Since AC_OUTPUT should be the last line of your configure.ac, anything after it will be run after config.status is run.

To make hello-world.sh execute after config.status, just append it to your configure.ac:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
$srcdir/hello.sh
```

$srcdir is required if building out of the srcdir.